# Short if form does not work

Tags: c#, if-statement, short

```
(myCondition!="true")
    ? output("false"); doSomethingElse();
    : output("true")
```

Why does the IDE say at the double-dot "Expected semicolon" ?

Comment: it should be (myCondition!="true") ? output("false") : output("true")

Comment: Do you really want us to fix your pseudo code? `"true"` is a `String`, is `myCondition` also a `String` or a `bool`? Why do you want to use the conditional operator at all? Use `if...else`

Comment: Leaving away the semicolons results in error. This is logical, since the compiler can not tell where the first expression ends

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Yes, why not? I try to understand WHY it does not work.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The point is that the OP doesn't think it *is* pseudo-code - the OP expects it to be valid code.

Comment: @JonSkeet: actually i thought it was pseudo code because of the `"true"`-condition. But perhaps it's the actual code, then OP should use `bool` instead of `string` (also for `myCondition`). Currently it's very confusing.

Comment: @Best_Where_Gives: In what way? If you didn't expect this to be valid code, then it's a bizarre question. Why would you ask why code that you knew to be invalid code doesn't compile

Comment: Because I wanted to know why the general idea is not possible this way. It´s not that hard to tell

Comment: @Best_Where_Gives: I don't think you're the best person to judge how clear your question is, given that it's caused confusion. If you're going to ask why code doesn't compile, don't give code that you wouldn't expect to compile in the first place! How are we meant to know which parts of the problem are you not bothering to provide real code, and which parts of the problem are you not understanding the language?

Answer (score 9):

The conditional operator isn't a "short if form"... it's an operator, which evaluates either the third operand or the second operand based on the evaluation of the first operand. The result of the whole expression is the result of whichever operand was evaluated (out of the 2nd/3rd), converted to the result type where necessary (either the 2nd and 3rd operands have to be of the same type, or there must be an implicit conversion of one to the other).

You can't use it as an individual statement, and you certainly can't have multiple statements as the operands. Note that it must evaluate to a value - if `Output` and `DoSomethingElse` are `void` methods, that's *another* reason why you couldn't use the conditional operator.

Just don't do it. When you want the execution model of an `if` statement, use an `if` statement.

```
// I generally try to make conditions positive where possible. It's easier to read IMO.
if (myCondition == "true")
{
    Output("true");
}
else
{
    Output("false");
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting that either the type of first and second expression must be the same or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other. The whole purpose of the operator is to assign a value, not to alter the control flow based on some condition like with an `if...else`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yup, added a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't intended to be a general replacement for 'if'. Rather, it's usually used to choose between two values;

```
 var clothing = isRaining ? hat : sunglasses;
```

What you're doing is better expressed with a classic if;

```
if (myCondition!="true") 
{
    output("false"); 
    doSomethingElse();
}
else
{
    output("true")
}
```

The actual problem you're having is that you've included two statements in the first branch;

```
output("false"); doSomethingElse();
```

and in this form, you can only have one statement, and it has to return a value. After `output("false") the language is expecting the`:` for the else-value; you're giving it a semi-colon and it's got confused.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed Answer